# Overriding the three slashes automatic documentation

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to automatically fill in the XML documentation created by Visual Studio when you type `///`?

I want to auto fill the documentation like the variable name separated based on camel casing.

I could write a Visual Studio Add-In and bind it to different key combination, but wanted to see if there is any other way to do so.

Comment: Just use GhostDoc (http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) might be able to help - it's excellent for generating XML comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) or Resharper with the [stylecop plugin](http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/).